# mysql syntax error in update with same table

Tags: mysql

The error showing

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

i think an error in the syntax

```
update invoice AS t1, 

(select sum(total_cost) from invoice where billno='X-0125' and item='11') AS t2 

set t1.total_cost=(t1.total_cost/(t2.sum(total_cost))*100
                
WHERE t1.billno='X-0125' and t1.item='11'
```

Comment: `set t1.total_cost=(t1.total_cost/(t2.sum(total_cost))*100` I Think you miss `)`

Answer (score 1):

Missing one paranthesis after '100' for example (depends on what you want) but missing one:

```
update
  invoice AS t1,
  (
    select
      sum(total_cost)
    from
      invoice
    where
      billno = 'X-0125'
      and item = '11'
  ) AS t2
set
  t1.total_cost =(t1.total_cost /(t2.sum(total_cost)) * 100)
WHERE
  t1.billno = 'X-0125'
  and t1.item = '11'
```